# true negative and false negative ero in confusion matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am doing protein structural class prediction using libsvm in matlab. Using my different dimensional feature sets I did 7 fold cross validation and got good result. But when I am trying to test data and get confusion matrix , I am getting values for only true positive and false negative, not getting any value for true negative and false positive.

I am really stuck and would be grateful if anyone help me by giving a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you compute them yourself? The accuracy gives you the total number of prediction "mistakes", so if you have 1000 test items and you get accuracy 80%, then `false negatives`+ `false positives` = 200. Since you have the number of `false negatives`, you can compute `false positives` = 200 - `false negatives`. Again, given the above accuracy, it means that `true negatives` + `true positives` = 800, so you can compute `true negatives` = 800 - `true positives`.

The above rationale should easily generalize to more dimensions, but I might be missing something here, so please clarify your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But in my case true positives and false false negatives  are showing wrong result. I am really confused. Since I am getting good result from sross validation is it possible to get wrong result for testing data ?

Comment: Yes, of course, depending how you constructed your test set. Let's say you take your training set, you randomize the order of the vectors in it and you divide it in 3 parts: 60% training data, 20% cross-validation data and 20% test data. In this case, I see no reason why the CV accuracy would differ (by much) from the test accuracy. If your current training data does not come from the same source as your test data, then, indeed, it can indeed give crappy results.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. My problem is I am getting wrong values for TP, TN,FP,FN.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. My problem is I am getting wrong values for TP, TN,FP,FN. Like I am testing with 200 class 1 data and 373 class -1 data whereas training with 243 class1 data and 857  data. It is giving me output like TP 535 and FN 38 ,TN 0 and FP 0. Here I am getting totally wrong result for testing. I am using dataset from same source for tesing. I did the sross validation with whole dataset. I am getting good result for CV but Is my classifier wrong as I am getting wrong result for tesing ?

Comment: Well, in this case you might have to go into more details and publish your dataset and the code that you use to call the libsvm subroutines. Even though there are lots of smart people here, I think you might have more luck getting a pertinent answer on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)